ROS1 to ROS2 Porting
i have to port a Software from ROS1 to ROS2 and i have just a good basic understanding of the two. In ROS2 i learned to make Nodes as a Class (oop), but it would be much easier for me to port it nearly one by one like the ROS1 Software. The thing is that the ROS1 Software  is programmed procedural. Now ive ported one .cpp File to ROS2 and i want to ask, if its ok how i did that. I will upload some pictures of the code for comparison. It would be nice if i get some Feedback because i can only move on with the porting when i know i have done it the right way. Its not about some tiny faults, i want to know if this would work at all, or i have to change it to the ROS2 oop style.
I cant build the code because i have some troubles to build it, so now i just want to know if this is done the right way, so that i can focus on the Cmake file and building.
Thank you in advance.
The ROS1 Code is commented out and below is the ROS2 Code.




Please paste any code or console output as code formatted text and not as a screenshot. Screenshots are not text searchable, amongst other things...

Ah sry, i will do that next time.

For a simple migration this looks fine to me

Thank you for your answer, this helped me a lot. So now i will try to get a running version. And then i try to make it the OOP way, to see if there are any performance differences.
